# Failing to import org.apache.commons

Tags: java, import, compiler-errors, compilation, javac

First line of `MyCode.java` is

```
import org.apache.commons.math3.distribution;
```

I am trying to compile via the command line with (I am on Mac OS X 10.12.4)

```
javac -cp "/Users/remi/Downloads/Java/commons-net-3.6/commons-net-3.6.jar"  MyCode.java
```

(the file really exist and it simply is in my downloads for the moment) but I get the error message

```
MyCode.java:1: error: package org.apache.commons.math3 does not exist
import org.apache.commons.math3.distribution;
                               ^
1 error
```

Can you help me out?

Comment: Did you add your lib to classpath? Problem is because compiler can not find the lib

Comment: What is my lib? I added `-cp <path>`, where `<path>` is the path to `commons-net-3.6.jar` which I would have thought would allow me to import   `org.apache.commons.math3.distribution` (but I am for the moment, very much lost in all that).

Comment: You are using the `org.apache.commons.math3.distribution` so you would need the [apache math](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/download_math.cgi) lib

Comment: Aahh.... ok. That was silly! It works! Thanks a lot! Do you want to make an answer out of your comments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the `org.apache.commons.math3.distribution` so you would need the [apache math](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/download_math.cgi) lib in your classpath. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the necessary JAR files are included in your build path.